# How to combine elements in two lists into one element in one list?

Tags: python

My problem is that I try to combine 2 lists:

```
alpha = ['red','white','blue']

beta = ['shirt','car','house']
```

into:

```
delta = ['red shirt','white car','blue house']
```

I tried to use `zip()`, but it returns: `[('red', 'shirt'), ('white', 'car'), ('blue', 'house')]`
which is not what I'm looking for.

How can I do it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are almost there. You are looking for a string join. `[' '.join(x) for x in zip(alpha, beta)]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to go one step further and create a joint string

```
[' '.join(group) for group in zip(alpha, beta)]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `map` with `join` over the lists zipped together:

```
list(map(' '.join, zip(alpha, beta)))

# ['red shirt', 'white car', 'blue house']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print([alpha[i]+" "+beta[i] for i in range(len(alpha))])
```

Gives me:

```
['red shirt', 'white car', 'blue house']
```

> Edit: actually others have posted better solutions than mine :-)